# How to make the custom newform.aspx as the default new form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, list-form, newform, default

I have created a custom newform.aspx using the copy of the existing Sharepoint 2010 list form using SP Designer tool.Now i want to make this mynewcustomform.aspx as the default form when the user clicks on the new item in my SPList.How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Open SP Designer
- In left side, click on "List and Libraries" in Site objects pane.
- All lists and libraries will open in right pane.
- Single click the desired list name.
- In extreme right side you can see a Forms Pane with list of all forms(Default and your custom forms).
- Select(single click) you custom form.
- In highlighted ribbon you can see a option "Set as Default". Click it, and your custom form is set to default.

Comment: how to create a  completely new custom form with custom html controls , sp client picker values etc in a sp 2013 list form

Answer (score 2):

You will have a Set as Default button visible in the ribbon if you select the form. Go to Lists and Libraries -> Choose List -> In the forms section, choose your form -> Click on Set as Default in the top ribbon.

Answer (score 1):

In SP designer when you open settings of the list where you have on right side forms part. When you click button **New..** Choose NewForm and than check checkbox that says **set as default**.

Answer (score 1):

Open your site in SharePoint Designer and navigate to your list. In the Forms section, select your custom newform.aspx page and in the Ribbon click Set as Default.

Comment: After adding the changes when I went back to the list and clicked the new item, its still navigating to the old newform.aspx.Its not pointing to my newcustomform.aspx which I made as a default newform.aspx.Any idea  why this is  happening? I saved my page and checked-in also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to be set up automatically. You can create a custom list definition and change the Form-Node
e.g.:

```
<List>
...
  <MetaData>
    <Forms>
     <Form Type="DisplayForm" Url="DispForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
     <Form Type="EditForm" Url="EditForm.aspx" SetupPath="pages\form.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
     <Form Type="NewForm" Url="NewForm.aspx" SetupPath="features\$SharePoint.Feature.DeploymentPath$\mynewcustomform.aspx" WebPartZoneID="Main" />
    </Forms>
  </MetaData>
</List>
```