# Created a form that I am trying to use to create a workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, custom-form, newform

Full discretion: Novice at SharePoint - any help is appreciated.

I created a form that I am trying to have linked to a workflow that I have based off a list I created. I understand that in Designer you can mark to have workflows 'start automatically when an item is created' however I am not sure how to link the form to the workflow. It is currently published in a Form library that I created on SharePoint.

If you all have any insight, or could post a link to a solution I would appreciate it!

Comment: So you have a custom form in a Form library, let's call it Location A.  Is the new custom associated with a separate list, Location B?  You need to make your new form the default so that SP uses it when create 'new item' is selected.  Regarding the workflow this should work once SP is configured to use your new form.

Comment: This link [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/158786/how-to-make-the-custom-newform-aspx-as-the-default-new-form-in-sharepoint-2010/158790#158790) looks helpful